# How to add another top level node

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have my linq code formatted like:

```
<Deck>
   <Treasure>
     <card>
     .....
     </card>
     ......
   </treasure>
   <Door>
     <card>
     .....
     </card>
     ......
   </Door>
```

In the following code how do I add another Door that is the same "level" as treasure? Everything I have tried keeps adding it as the same level as card. Here is what I have:

```
   public void SaveXml(string path)
    {
        XElement xml;
        XElement root = new XElement("Treasure");
        foreach (var item in TreasureCards)
        {
            xml = new XElement("Card",
                    new XAttribute("name", item.Name),
                    new XElement("Type", item.Type),
                    new XElement("Image",
                    new XAttribute("path", item.Image)),
                    new XElement("Usage", item.Usage),
                    new XElement("Quantity", item.Quantity),
                    new XElement("Sell", item.Sell)
                    );
            root.Add(xml);
        }
        root.Add(new XElement("Door"));
        foreach (var item in DoorCards)
        {
            xml = new XElement("Card",
                  new XAttribute("name", item.Name),
                  new XElement("Type", item.Type),
                  new XElement("Image",
                  new XAttribute("path", item.Image)),
                  new XElement("Usage", item.Usage),
                  new XElement("Quantity", item.Quantity));
            root.Add(xml);
        }
```

Comment: Your `root` is the `Treasure` element. So `root.Add` is going to add the element as a child of `Treasure`. You need `root` to be the `Deck` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the Deck element first:

```
XElement deck = new XElement("Deck");
```

Then add both the treasure (which i've taken the liberty of renaming from root to treasure) and the door to it:

```
XElement treasure = new XElement("Treasure")
...
deck.Add(treasure)
...
XElement door = new XElement("Door")
...
deck.Add(door)
```